# Restore database in remote SQL server using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

I am working on restoring a database backup on a local server and restore in a remote SQL server. I see an error

> "Exception calling "SqlRestore" with "1" argument(s): "Restore failed
>   for Server server\instance at  line:74 char:5"

Not sure where is the issue. Please see code below.

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('Microsoft.SqlServer.SMO') | out-null
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SqlServer.SmoExtended") | Out-Null
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo") | Out-Null
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SqlServer.SmoEnum") | Out-Null
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SqlServer.SqlEnum") | Out-Null

if($useSqlServerAuthentication)
{

    $passwordSecureString = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $pwd -AsPlainText -Force;
    $serverConnection = new-object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ServerConnection $SR, $user, $passwordSecureString;
    $smoserver = new-object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server $serverConnection;
}
else
{
    $smoserver = new-object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server $SR;
    write-host $smoserver
}

$dataFolder = $smoserver.Settings.DefaultFile;
$logFolder = $smoserver.Settings.DefaultLog;

if ($dataFolder.Length -eq 0)
{
    $dataFolder = $smoserver.Information.MasterDBPath;
}
if ($logFolder.Length -eq 0) 
{
    $logFolder = $smoserver.Information.MasterDBLogPath;
}

$backupDeviceItem = new-object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.BackupDeviceItem $restorefile, 'File';
$restore = new-object 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Restore';
$restore.Database = $Db;
$restore.Devices.Add($backupDeviceItem);

$dataFileNumber = 0;

foreach ($file in $restore.ReadFileList($server)) 
{
    $relocateFile = new-object 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.RelocateFile';
    $relocateFile.LogicalFileName = $file.LogicalName;
    if ($file.Type -eq 'D')
    {
        if($dataFileNumber -ge 1) { $suffix = "_$dataFileNumber"; }
        else { $suffix = $null; }
        $relocateFile.PhysicalFileName = "$dataFolder$DB.mdf";
        $dataFileNumber ++;
    }
    else 
    {
        $relocateFile.PhysicalFileName = "$logFolder\$DatabaseName$suffix.ldf";
    }
    $restore.RelocateFiles.Add($relocateFile) | out-null;
}    
$restore.SqlRestore($smoserver)
```

Comment: any help on the above? I am working on automating always on configuration and not able to complete it due to this restore issue.

Comment: Try to comment out this line and see if the error still presents itself. "$restore.Devices.Add($backupDeviceItem);"

Comment: commented the $restore.Devices.Add($backupDeviceItem); and still see the same message.

Comment: Ok, so what specifically is line 74, because the script posted only ~54 lines. That will help us narrow down the cause..

Comment: Line 74 is the last line of the above script. I tried the normal way to restore with no recovery as shown below and it worked successfully. Thank you all for the suggestions and assistance.




************************************************************************************************
Restore-SqlDatabase -serverinstance $SR -Database $db -BackupFile "$restorefile"  -NoRecovery -ReplaceDatabase -FileNumber 0

Comment: No idea what I did but glad you got it working xD